# jQuery Autocomplete focus fired multiple times

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have big problems figuring out, why that `outter focus` event is fired multiple times. Every time i click in that input field the event gets fired again and again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('focus', '.aSuggest', function(event) {

    var aTags = [
      "ask",
      "always",
      "all",
      "alright",
      "one",
      "foo",
      "blackberry",
      "tweet",
      "force9",
      "westerners",
      "sport"
    ];

    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: aTags,
      minLength: 0,
      delay: 500,
      focus: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("focus");
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("select");
      },
      open: function() {
        console.log("open");
      },
    }).focus(function(event) {
      console.log("outter focus");
    });
  });
});
```

**What i want to do:**

I want to initialize the autocomplete in the focus event of the input field. Whenever the input field has a value and loose focus and then the input field will gain focus again the result from autocomplete should open again.
I know how to do that, but the problem is, that the event is fired multiple times.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/xbjmae8c/10/

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $aSuggestAutocomplete;

    $(document).on('focusin', '.aSuggest', function(event) {
    console.log('focusin');
    if (this.value) {
        console.log('autocomplete search triggered from .aSuggest');
        $aSuggestAutocomplete.autocomplete("search", this.value);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('focus', '.aSuggest', function(event) {

    var aTags = [
      "ask",
      "always",
      "all",
      "alright",
      "one",
      "foo",
      "blackberry",
      "tweet",
      "force9",
      "westerners",
      "sport"
    ];

    $aSuggestAutocomplete = $(this).autocomplete({
      source: aTags,
      minLength: 0,
      delay: 500,
      focus: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("focus");
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("select");
      },
      open: function() {
        console.log("open");
      },
    })/*.focus(function(event) {
      console.log("outter focus");
    });
    */
  });
});
```